# disable an ImageButton?

Tags: android, imagebutton

I wanted to leave an `ImageButton` is **disabled** (not clickable) but have used `android: enabled = "false"` and does't work.

Does anyone know how to **disable** an `ImageButton`?

Answer (score 29):

If you want to show the button as disabled (if you have that set up in an xml drawable file) doing both `setClickable(false)` AND `setEnabled(false)` will do the trick.

Comment: Note that setting these attributes does prevent the imagebutton from being clicked, but it doesn't grey the button out like it would on a normal button

Answer (score 17):

You can use the [`android:clickable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:clickable) attribute on the XML, or the [`setClickable(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClickable(boolean)) method from your code.

Comment: If you want to make it look grayed out, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14128907/832776

Answer (score 12):

When setting a clicklistener for the `ImageButton`, under the hood android resets the attribute clickable to `true`. That's why setting `android:clickable="false"` in xml is not helpful.

In addition, setting the attribute `android:enabled="false"` in the xml didn't work for me as well.

What did work is only setting via the code:

```
ImageButton mBtnDelayCall = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.btnCallDelay);
mBtnDelayCall.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want to **disable** and **"grey out"** the image, I use the following (Kotlin):

Disable:

```
chevron_left.imageAlpha = 75 // 0 being transparent and 255 being opaque
chevron_left.isEnabled = false
```

Enable:

```
chevron_left.imageAlpha = 255
chevron_left.isEnabled = true
```

XML:

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/chevron_left"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:src="@drawable/chevron_left"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
```

**Note** that the your background color will define the color of the disabled state. Depends on your desired result.

Answer (score -1):

`ImageButton` like `ImageView` does not have `android:enabled="false"` attribute, because it is attribute of `TextView`. If you want make `enable = false` in XML for `ImageButton` you have to add `android:focusable="false"` and `android:clickable="false"`.

Comment: In fact, setting android:enabled to "false" DOES disable an ImageButton; the button doesn't receive lick events anymore. What it does not do is change the appearance of the button.