# Two-Way Data Binding: View is missing user defined type

Tags: android, android-layout, data-binding, android-view, 2-way-object-databinding

Today I found out about the very-recently-introduced [two-way data binding](https://halfthought.wordpress.com/2016/03/23/2-way-data-binding-on-android) capability  in the Android Studio preview, and decided to give it a try.

I have a very simple layout (code below), for composing and sending messages. What I was trying to achieve is having the button "[disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3118108/3372061)" (and in the future, have some different image accordingly) when there is no text entered in the field.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<data>
    <variable name="msg" type="String"/>
</data>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/new_message_input"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/hint_compose_message"
        android:inputType="textAutoCorrect|textMultiLine"
        android:text="@={msg}"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_send_message"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
        android:enabled="@{!new_message_input.text.isEmpty()}"
        android:clickable="@{!new_message_input.text.isEmpty()}"/>
</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

The example code in the first link shows that something like this should be enough:

```
<layout ...>
  <data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
  </data>
  <RelativeLayout ...>
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/seeAds" .../>
    <ImageView android:visibility="@{seeAds.checked ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" .../>
  </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

However, when trying to implement similar logic for the `enabled`/`clickable` properties of the `ImageButton`, I am getting the following error:

> Error:`java.lang.RuntimeException`: `java.lang.RuntimeException`: Found data binding errors.
>   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. `new_message_input` is missing it

The problem is definitely with these two lines, since removing them allows the binding class to be properly created.

My questions are:

- **What am I doing wrong?**
- **How can I resolve this?**

---

I also tried doing it a bit differently, but the result was the same:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
<data>
    <import type="android.widget.EditText"/>
    ...
</data>
<LinearLayout
  ...
  <ImageButton
    ...
    android:enabled="@{!(((EditText)new_message_input).getText().toString().isEmpty())}"
    android:clickable="@{!(((EditText)new_message_input).getText().toString().isEmpty())}"/>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Doh.*

It slipped my mind that the the Data Binding process converts XML IDs to properties in the Binding class, all of which are written in **lower camel case**. This means that in order to refer to `"@id/new_message_input"` from within `"@id/btn_send_message"` using data binding, I should have used the **generated name**, which in this case was `newMessageInput`.

This was not immediately evident from the example because it contained a `View` whose `@id` was already in *camelCase* and therefore identical to the the generated name - thus working automagically.

The solution was therefore to replace these lines:

```
    android:enabled="@{!new_message_input.text.isEmpty()}"
    android:clickable="@{!new_message_input.text.isEmpty()}"/>
```

with:

```
    android:enabled="@{!newMessageInput.text.isEmpty()}"
    android:clickable="@{!newMessageInput.text.isEmpty()}"/>
```

Or I could completely get around this problem if I did:

```
    android:enabled="@{!msg.isEmpty()}"
    android:clickable="@{!msg.isEmpty()}"/>
```

---

#### On a side note:

If the `EditText` is initially empty (and therefore we would expect the button to be disabled), we should attach an empty `String` object to the view (through Java; e.g. `StringUtils.EMPTY`), at the time of layout inflation, to correctly make the button unclickable.